# How can I see how long statements take to execute on the mysql command line?

Tags: mysql, debian

When I execute statements on the mysql command line, there must be some way to always display how long the command took to execute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does show that info for every command executed:

```
mysql> select md5('dkejde');
+----------------------------------+
| md5('dkejde')                    |
+----------------------------------+
| 3960c3b0aa4acc97ca277cdea69775fd | 
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)

mysql> show databases;
...
38 rows in set (0.29 sec)
```

You don't see that?